# D3 is giving TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data is not a function when trying to update dots in graph using transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have two functions firstLineChart and updateFirstLineChart. firstLineChart is used to render data intially and the basic code in its look like this

```
var svg = d3.select(node)
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("transform", "translate(50,-170)")
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left+ "," + margin.top + ")");
    x.domain(d3.extent(finalData, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(finalData, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(finalData));
    svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(finalData)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class",'dot')
      .attr("r",4)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
      .style("fill", "white")
            .style("stroke", "blue")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
                div.html(d.date + "<br/>" + d.close)
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                div.transition()
                    .duration(400)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
            });
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

It is working fine and I can get the scatter plot graph using this code. IN updateFirstLineChart I am updating the graph for a different set of data when a particular action is done. It is rendering the graph if the code to update dots is not given but while I am trying to update the dots, I am getting `TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data is not a function` error. The code i am trying is as below

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                .style("opacity", 0);
  var svg = d3.select(node).transition();
  svg.selectAll(".dot").remove();
  svg.selectAll(".tooltip").remove();
  var valueline = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5);

  var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5);
// Make the changes
  svg.select(".line")   // change the line
      .duration(750)
      .attr("d", valueline(finalData));
  svg.selectAll("dot")
  .data(finalData)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class",'dot')
  .attr("r",4)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.close); })
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke", "blue")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    div.html(d.date + "<br/>" + d.close)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(400)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
  svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
      .duration(750)
      .call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
      .duration(750)
      .call(yAxis);
```

Please help me with this, I am new to d3 and I dont know were I am doing wrong.

Comment: `svg` holds a reference to a transition object and, thus, `svg.selectAll("dot")` also returns a transition which does not feature a `.data()` method by design. You need a selection to bind data instead.

Comment: so how should i use it, Please help me with code

Comment: Hard to tell how to do it correctly given the code you provided. Can you set up a [mcve]? Keep in mind, though, that it should be really that: **minimal**, stripped down to the essential problem, which means that all the formatting and any other distracting code segments should be removed.

Comment: in my experience you rarely (if ever) need separate methods for rendering initial data and updating it